# SQL Server On Linux and SQL Server version tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, in addition to the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag, you have the version tags (e.g. [sql-server-2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2014)), and the [sql-server-on-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-on-linux). With SQL Server 2019, you now have 2 different versions of SQL Server on Linux available (2017 and 2019).

Would it be worth adding [sql-server-2017-on-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2017-on-linux) and [sql-server-2019-on-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2019-on-linux) tags instead and merging the existing [sql-server-on-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-on-linux) tag into the 2017 one?

I ask, as many users don't follow the version tags, they follow the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag, however, if a user is using SQL Server on Linux, and wants to tag their version and that they are using Linux, that now requires 3 tags: [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), [sql-server-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2019), [sql-server-on-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-on-linux).

Knowing the version and if it's on Linux can make a big difference to the question, due to supported features, so more succinct tags could help identify those.

Comment: [tag:I-m-not-a-fan-of-long-tag-names-instead-use-SOL-2017-and-SOL-2019] ...

Comment: Lol, certainly we could suggest synonyms to abbreviate the displayed name, @rene .

Comment: I'm wondering if this needs to be done now. With 12 questions currently I think having 2019 or 2017 in the post body would be easy enough for the experts to figure out what the question is about and if they want to rule out 2017 from their search results they still can do that with negative match on the year?

Comment: The `sql-server-on-linux` tag is very underutilised at the monent, @rene . Probably because users don't know it exists; and why this might actually be more beneficial.

Comment: [sql-server] [linux] has 396 questions, the simple and obvious way to tag such a question.

Comment: @HansPassant that doesn't mean SQL Server On Linux. That could mean a Windows SQL Server Instance and the OP is using a Linux environment to communicate with it. That would be like tagging docker Linux and assuming that it means the docker container is running Linux; rather than the host OS.

Answer (score 2):

I choose to simply follow [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) with a wildcard `*` appended to avoid listing specific versions.

<sup>(Meta doesn't tag it with an asterix [tag:sql-server*])</sup>

This provides results like so:

[SQL Server Wildcard Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server*)

Comment: Nice. Too bad this doesn't work with custom filters

Comment: @ThomasSchremser how do you mean?

Comment: I'm talking about the newly implemented [custom filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330326/392713) which let you define tags to watch and then access them from the sidebar. I tried to add a `*` to one of mine but it is discarded upon saving.

Comment: It would be nice if you could use this for the custom filters. I (effectively) follow `sql-server*` and `tsql`, but as `sql-server*` isn't supported I have to list them all out.